# Possible to ask this question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

My question is:

> I frequently use a search box on a particular website. I would like to
>   search for an exact phrase in this search box. However when I try the
>   standard double quote "" used in Google Search box I get no results.
>   This indicates to me that this particular search box does not support
>   the double quote syntax. How may I uncover the syntax that this search
>   box is using to extract the results I desire?

I've had negative feedback on my previous questions on Stack Overflow so I would rather avoid getting downvoted and receive the approval of the Meta community first.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a _programming_ question, so no. That said, I'm not sure if it would fit the rules of other sites either, so someone else will have to speak to that. (If you do mean it to be a programming question, you'll need a lot more detail to make it even remotely sound like one. It currently sounds more like a general computer/web usage question.)

Comment: You don't understand what is and is not on topic here.  You should probably not post any questions until you are absolutely 100% sure you get it.

Comment: possible, sure, but it wouldn't be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is absolutely 100% off-topic on Stack Overflow so you were right to check first.  It isn't a specific programming problem (it's not even about programming), so there is really no way to modify the question to make it on-topic.

You ***might*** find help on [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help), but even looking at their scope, I'm not convinced it is the right place because a search engine is not really a "Web App" in the sense described in the help page.

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> Web Applications Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of
>   web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which
>   behaves like an application Bookmarklets Features of browsers which
>   are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey
>   scripts for a web application, etc.) … then you’re in the right place
>   to ask your question!

You may want to explore their [meta site](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/) or ask there.

You could also try asking for [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) on [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) to see if the broader SE community can help find a specific SE site where the question might be on-topic.